# Why I see everything which is red in 3D with my prescription eyeglasses?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, lenses, vision

I have prescription eyeglasses with -1.5D power (Myopia). I have been wearing eyeglasses for past 5 years and recently changed to blue light filter ones. Now I recognise everything red in colour as a bit projected than blue colours. Especially in all these anaglyph images like:

[image]

[image]

and even with non-anaglyph photos like:

[image].

In Videos with Intros in Black and Red, I see Red in 3D. I would be really glad to know what might be the reason? Is it that the blue light filter blocks blue light and red is projected like a half 3D (red-blue) glass? I tried showing the same images with my glass to my parents and siblings and they were also amazed to see it in 3D!

PS: I see things normally with my non-coated eyewear.

Comment: Wow! Just confirmed this.  Welcome to the Physics stack exchange, btw!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be about the human perceptual apparatus, which isn’t really physics.

Comment: Hi @rob Can I know why the human perceptual apparatus isn't really physics? Where should I ask this doubt then?

Comment: @rob It seems like a question about the optics of the filtered lenses, not a question about the eye. I think this could be on topic, although answering it probably involves knowing some engineering details about how these specific lenses work.

Comment: @d_b thanks for supporting my question (^_^)

Comment: @AlphaLife I'm happy you checked it out. But I still wonder why even only some of my friends with coated eyewears could see it in 3d and not all.

Comment: I vote to reopen because the reason is probably that the focal point of the red light is different from that of the blue, because the lenses exhibit a nontrivial amount of *dispersion*. This is a common problem with cheap plastic eyeglass lenses, and to avoid it you must specify *low-dispersion* lens material.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Thanks for the explanation! One more ques. Is it harmful to continue wearing my present eyewear?

Comment: It is not harmful but you will notice that in poor lighting conditions, the dispersion effect reduces your effective visual acuity to the point where you stop receiving the benefits of the eyeglasses themselves. This happened to me, and I had to get new lenses made from *low-dispersion* plastic. This solved the problem!

Comment: @nielsnielsen Thanks!

Comment: I changed opticians when getting new reading glasses. The new ones make computer red/black/blue screen icons appear 3 dimensional.. some colours appear nearer than others…the only other time I experienced this multiple—plane effect was when looking through the opticians equiptment ..

Answer (score 2):

The reason is probably that the focal point of the red light is different from that of the blue, because the lenses exhibit a nontrivial amount of *dispersion*. This is a common problem with cheap plastic eyeglass lenses, and to avoid it you must specify *low-dispersion* lens material.